# Different CAML statements needed in development and test anvironments

Tags: updatelistitems

I have a .NET solution which uses the SharePoint web services interface to update meta data for existing documents in a SharePoint library. However, I am finding that I need to supply different CAML update commands for my development system compared to our test environment (both environments contain several hundred test documents).

In my development environment I can use a CAML statement of the form:

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" PreCalc="TRUE">
  <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
     <Field Name="ID"></Field>
     <Field Name="FileRef">http://SPDevServer/sites/GovTrng/OTA/Dev Tax Returns/H000111/Test Doc.docx</Field>
     <Field Name="Tax_x0020_Reference">C12346</Field>
  </Method>
</Batch>
```

However, in my test environment I have to use a CAML statement of the form:

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" PreCalc="TRUE">
  <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
     <Field Name="ID">1234</Field>
     <Field Name="FileRef">http://SPTestServer/sites/GovTrng/OTA/Test Doc.docx</Field>
     <Field Name="Tax_x0020_Reference">C12346</Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

i.e. I need to supply the SharePoint document ID in the CAML update command. If I don't supply the ID I get the error shown below:

```
<Results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <Result ID="1,Update">
       <ErrorCode>0x80070005</ErrorCode>
       <ErrorText>The operation failed because an unexpected error occurred. (Result Code: 0x80070005)</ErrorText>
    </Result>
</Results>
```

Why the difference and how can I tell in what circumstance I need to supply the document ID?

I know I could probably get away with always supplying the ID but this involves an extra call to SharePoint which ideally I want to avoid.

Many thanks

Nigel

Answer (score 0):

I think this must be something to do with the `Document ID Service` state on the two different environments. Is it Active on the Test site collection, but not Dev?